# Node.js v6 ES6 App Structure Changes

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules

Node v6 comes with 93% ES6 implementation. Has already anything changed in how to write node applications? Have classes already replaced node-modules syntactically or something like that?

Comment: Check the node docs. Arrow functions everywhere.

Comment: How would classes replace node-modules?

Comment: Classes and modules are two different things. One is not a substitute for the other.